# Google Analytics Measurement Protocol Measuring Transaction but not Product Data

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Given the payload:

```
v=1
&tid=UA-REDACTED
&ds=web
&cid=REDACTED
&uid=15844
&uip=REDACTED
&ua=Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3b+Win64%3b+x64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f68.0.3440.106+Safari%2f537.36
&ul=en-gb
&dp=%2f
&dh=www.devserver.com
&t=transaction
&ti=TestTxn8TI
&tr=105
&tt=10
&ts=5
&cu=EUR
&ds=web
&pr1id=testsku
&pr1nm=test%20product%20description
&pr1ca=hardware
&pr1pr=100
&pr1qt=1
&pr2id=testsku2
&pr2nm=another%20description
&pr2ca=hardware
&pr2pr=20
&pr2qt=2
&pa=purchase
```

It's correctly measuring the transaction:

[image]

However no associated product data.  How do I get the product data to show?

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact you had `pa` in there. So that's not the issue.

Comment: How are you sending the payload to GA? Are you generating the above and sending it directly to the API endpoint? Or are you using a JS/Python/etc library?

Comment: @vinoaj sending in C# with HttpWebRequest

Comment: I suspect there may be an encoding issue when the hit is transmitted. Is the above example from an actual hit that is dispatched?

Comment: Yes is from an actual hit.  Am encoding all posted hit data as ASCII

Comment: I really can't see anything wrong with your hit. Sometimes there is a reporting delay. If you click into "TextTxn8TI" now are you able to see any products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you're mixing Ecommerce hits, with Enhanced Ecommerce hit.

According to Measurement Protocol documentation for [Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#enhancedecom):

> Important: Enhanced Ecommerce parameters must be sent with an existing hit (e.g. pageview, event), but cannot be sent with the Ecommerce transaction or item hit types.

With that being said, to continue sending the hit under [Ecommerce Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#ecom):

1. Trigger a Transaction Hit

   ```
   v=1
   &tid=UA-XXXXX-Y
   &cid=555
   &t=transaction
   &ti=TestTxn8TI
   &tr=105
   &ts=5
   &tt=10
   &cu=EUR
   ```
2. Trigger Item Hit for each product in the transaction

   ```
   v=1
   &tid=UA-XXXXX-Y
   &cid=555
   &t=item
   &ti=testsku
   &in=test%20product%20description
   &ip=100
   &iq=1
   &iv=hardware
   &cu=EUR

   v=1
   &tid=UA-XXXXX-Y
   &cid=555
   &t=item
   &ti=testsku2
   &in=another%20description
   &ip=20
   &iq=2
   &iv=hardware
   &cu=EUR
   ```

If you're interested in sending the hit under Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking, simply change the Hit Type from `transaction` to `pageview`, like:

```
    v=1
    &tid=UA-XXXXX-Y
    &cid=555
    &t=pageview
    &dh=www.devserver.com
    &dp=%2f
    &ds=web
    &uid=15844
    &uip=REDACTED
    &ua=Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0%3b+Win64%3b+x64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f68.0.3440.106+Safari%2f537.36
    &ul=en-gb
    &ti=TestTxn8TI
    &tr=105
    &tt=10
    &ts=5
    &cu=EUR
    &pa=purchase
    &pr1id=testsku
    &pr1nm=test%20product%20description
    &pr1ca=hardware
    &pr1pr=100
    &pr1qt=1
    &pr2id=testsku2
    &pr2nm=another%20description
    &pr2ca=hardware
    &pr2pr=20
    &pr2qt=2
```

Hope that helps!